# Unable to make tree expand all in Angular

Tags: angular

Hi I am working on Angular 5 project. I am having multiple trees in my web page. I want to expand all nodes by default when tree loaded. Below are my trees.

```
@ViewChild(TreeComponent)
public treecreate: TreeComponent;

@ViewChild(TreeComponent)
public treedelete: TreeComponent;

@ViewChild(TreeComponent)
public treeupdate: TreeComponent;

@ViewChild(TreeComponent)
public treeread: TreeComponent;
```

Below is my html implementation.

```
   <tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs" [heading]="tabz.title">
                                        <div *ngIf="tabz.title ==='CREATE'">
                                            <tree-root #treecreate
                                                       [nodes]="tabz.content"
                                                       [options]="options" (updateData)="onUpdateData($event)">

                                                <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target,node,tabz.title)"
                                                           [checked]="node.data.checked" id="cbcreate">
                                                    {{ node.data.name }}
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </tree-root>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="tabz.title==='DELETE'">
                                            <tree-root #treedelete
                                                       [nodes]="tabz.content"
                                                       [options]="options">

                                                <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target,node,tabz.title)"
                                                           [checked]="node.data.checked" id="cbdelete">
                                                    {{ node.data.name }}
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </tree-root>
                                        </div>
                                        <div *ngIf="tabz.title==='UPDATE'">
                                            <tree-root #treeupdate
                                                       [nodes]="tabz.content"
                                                       [options]="options">

                                                <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target,node,tabz.title)"
                                                           [checked]="node.data.checked" id="cbupdate">
                                                    {{ node.data.name }}
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </tree-root>
                                        </div>

                                        <div *ngIf="tabz.title==='READ'">
                                            <tree-root #treeread
                                                       [nodes]="tabz.content"
                                                       [options]="options">

                                                <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target,node,tabz.title)"
                                                           [checked]="node.data.checked" id="cbread">
                                                    {{ node.data.name }}
                                                </ng-template>
                                            </tree-root>
                                        </div>
                                    </tab>
```

Below code is for load nodes.

```
addrule(){
     this.arrayTabs.forEach(eachObj => {
                if (eachObj == "CREATE") {
                    this.tabs.push({
                        title: eachObj,
                        active: false,
                        content: this.createnode
                    });
                }
                if (eachObj == "UPDATE") {
                    this.tabs.push({
                        title: eachObj,
                        active: false,
                        content: this.updatenode
                    });
                }
                if (eachObj == "DELETE") {
                    this.tabs.push({
                        title: eachObj,
                        active: false,
                        content: this.deletenode
                    });
                }
                if (eachObj == "READ") {
                    this.tabs.push({
                        title: eachObj,
                        active: false,
                        content: this.readnode
                    });
                }
            })
    }
}
```

I am trying to make expand all nodes by default. I tried as below.

```
 this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();
```

This is throwing error cannot read property undefined of treemodel

Can someone help me to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you call `this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();` from? Which function? Can you add that block of code please?

Comment: Thanks, As soon as tree loaded i want to expand all nodes. In the above code only I have added this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();

Comment: Okay, so where have you added it? In which function?

Comment: I have addrule function. inside addrule function i am loading nodes

Comment: And where is `addrule` called from? From the constructor? From `ngOnInit`? From a button click event?

Comment: it is called on button click. Once user licks on button I am displaying popup and loading tree using addrule function

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I am getting few nodes from api and few nodes are dynamic. APIS are not hosted.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the entire code, just the minimum amount that can reproduce the error. As it stands, I can't reproduce this issue with the code provided.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-jpkajy?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts